# Google Contacts Api - 401 error when access User Contact

Tags: google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I am using oauth 1.0 and until now I can successfully get the Access Token from Google.
But when I want to retrieve user contacts from **https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full**, it return 401 error and no further explanation.

I find that the information form Google playground may not be really accurate, for example the signature base string in step 3 and step 5 include oauth_version but it is wrong. (If you include oauth_version, it will return signature_invalid and oauth_version is not included )

**This is my request :**

```
   HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sbGetContacts.ToString());
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.Headers.Add(authHeader);
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

**This is my header:**

```
        string authHeader = "Authorization: OAuth " +
        "oauth_version=" + "\"" + "1.0" + "\"" + "\"," +
        "oauth_nonce=" + "\"" + nonce + "\"," +
        "oauth_timestamp=" + "\"" + timeStamp + "\"," +
        "oauth_consumer_key=" + "\"" + GoogleconsumerKey + "\"," +
        "oauth_token=" + "\"" + OauthToken+ "\"," +
        "oauth_signature_method=" + "\"" + "HMAC-SHA1" + "\"," +
        "oauth_signature=" + "\"" + UpperCaseUrlEncode(sig) + "\"";
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth1 is [deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) (by Google). Please don't spend any energy writing new code using OAuth1. With OAuth2 there are no signatures and crypto.
Is there a reason you need to use OAuth1? We would like to know. I work on OAuth at Google.

Answer (score 0):

Actually:

> If your application has certain unusual authorization requirements,
>   such as logging in at the same time as requesting data access (hybrid)
>   or domain-wide delegation of authority (2LO), then you cannot
>   currently use OAuth 2.0 tokens. In such cases, you must instead use
>   OAuth 1.0 tokens and an API key. You can find your application's API
>   key in the Google API Console, in the Simple API Access section of the
>   API Access pane.

According to https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=fr

So you need to pass an API key. You can do this be adding key='YOUR_API_KEY' to the URL
but how do you pass an API key if you are using a gdata client library?

Comment: i am hitting this url https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full and also tried same url with email replacing default keyword ......but i am getting the frustated 401 error .....